# How to attach function to second element of ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I just started learning angular
and I have a question related to `ng-repeater`

I have an `ng-repeater` like:

```
<div ng-if="!promo.promotion.useHTML"
     class="{{promo.promotion.monetateId}}"
     ng-repeat="promo in promotions track by promo.promotion.slotId">
  <div ng-if="!promo.useHTML">
  <img ng-src="{{promo.promotion.imageURL}}"
       ng-click="promoOnClick(promo.promotion.promotionURL)"/>
</div>
```

I want to have a different `ng-click` function on second element of repeater.

How would I get this?

Comment: Detect which item was clicked from the handler and act accordingly, you could do that by passing some relevant information to the handler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using $index variable which contains the repeater array offset index. You can use it to build conditional statements in your repeater.

```
<div ng-if="!promo.promotion.useHTML" class="{{promo.promotion.monetateId}}" ng-repeat="promo in promotions track by promo.promotion.slotId">
    <div ng-if="!promo.useHTML && $index !== 2">
        <img ng-src="{{promo.promotion.imageURL}}" ng-click="promoOnClick(promo.promotion.promotionURL)"/>
    </div>
    <div ng-if="!promo.useHTML && $index == 2">
        <img ng-src="{{promo.promotion.imageURL}}" ng-click="promoOnClickAnotherFunction(promo.promotion.promotionURL)"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

Or as suggested by comment below

```
<div ng-if="!promo.promotion.useHTML" class="{{promo.promotion.monetateId}}" ng-repeat="promo in promotions track by promo.promotion.slotId">
    <div ng-if="!promo.useHTML>
        <img ng-src="{{promo.promotion.imageURL}}" ng-click="($index==1) ? function1() : function2()"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

or as a third option, you can pass the index into the callback function as a second parameter and move your logic into your controller.

and in your callback, check the index and ... based on the index call your 
function1, or function 2. Its a good idea to move logic away from your templates/views.

even better option would be creating/setting your promote() function function in your controller. E.g when you load your promotions array/objects, loop over them and set their promote function based on ... whatever your requirements are.

```
var i;
var yourPromoteFunctionForSecondElement = function( promo_object ) {
    /*do your promo specific stuff here*/
}
for (i = 0; i < promotions.length; i++) {
    var promotion = promotions[i];
    if ( i == 1 ) {promotion.promote = yourPromoteFunctionForSecondElement(promotion);}
    else if () {promotion.promote = someOtherPromoteFunction(promotion);}
    else {/*etc*/}

}
```

Comment: Arrays are zero indexed, but good answer.  To shave some code, maybe add to your answer that one can evaluate ternary expressions:  `ng-click='($index==1) ? goHere() : goThere()'`.